# Erro ao criar script de execução da biblioteca ts-node-dev

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, yarn

Estou construindo o back-end de uma aplicação utilizando Node.js e Typescript, resolvi criar um script no package.json para facilitar a execução do sistema

Inseri o seguinte script:
`"scripts": { "build": "tsc","dev:server": "ts-node-dev --inspect --transpileOnly --ignore node_modules src/server.ts" },`

inclui a flag **--inspect** que possibilita que o vscode se conecte ao nosso código node em ambiente de desenvolvimento, e as flags **--transpileOnly** e **--ignore node_modules** para que me possibilite uma execução mais rápida.

porém ao executar utilizando o comando `yarn dev:server`

recebo o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consegui resolver completamente, busquei na rede e encontrei no https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev
o comando: **yarn add ts-node-dev --dev**

Executando essa comando  conseguigo correr a aplicação porém sem as **flags**.

Comment: O correto não seria `--inspect` ao invés de `-inspect`? Na imagem parece que você usou somente um hífen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O --transpileOnly mudou nessa nova versão do ts-node-dev para --trasnpile-only.

use o seguinte comando no seu script do package.json

ts-node-dev --transpile-only --ignore-watch node_modules src/[nome_do_arquivo_principal].ts